# cannot edit my document using ui-router within an angular-meteor app

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I am building my first angular-meteor app using the ui-router.
From a bookList view you can access the bookDetail template:

[image]

here's the book detail page:

[image]

From the detail page I would like to access the 'edit page'. This page should return the same data of the document detail page so that the user is able to edit it and save it. But I am failing. Please check my code below:

1) The ui-router configuration

```
 //Router
 angular.module('bookshelf',['angular-meteor', 'ui.router']);
 //Router configuration

         angular.module('bookshelf').config(['$urlRouterProvider',
        '$stateProvider','$locationProvider',
     function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider
  .state('books', {
    url: '/books',
    templateUrl: 'bookList.ng.html',
    controller: 'BookListCtrl'
  })
  .state('bookAdd', {
    url: '/books/add',
    templateUrl: 'addBook.ng.html',
    controller: 'bookAddCtrl'

  })
  .state('bookDetail', {
    url: '/books/:bookId',
    templateUrl: 'bookDetail.ng.html',
    controller: 'bookDetailCtrl'
  })
  .state('bookEdit', {
    url: '/edit/books/:bookId',
    templateUrl: 'bookEdit.ng.html',
    controller: 'bookEditlCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/books');
  }]);
```

2) The html template 'bookEdit.ng.html':

```
<div class="container">
<form  ng-controller="bookEditCtrl">
<label>Title</label>
<input ng-model="book.title">
<label>Author</label>
<input ng-model="book.author">
<label>Publisher</label>
<input ng-model="book.publisher">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
 ng-click="save(book)">Save</button>

</form>
</div>
```

3) The 'bookEditCtrl' controller from my app.js file:

```
     angular.module('bookshelf').controller('bookEditCtrl', 
     ['$scope','$stateParams','$meteor',
     function($scope,$stateParams,$meteor){

      $scope.book = $meteor.object(books, $stateParams.bookId);
      $scope.save = function(){
        $scope.book.save();
      };


    }]);
```

this is the result when I try to go to the edit page. 
[image]

The console shows an error. How can I get the book details in the input fields so that I can edit them and save them? Am I doing something wrong with the routing? Probably I should add within the input fields an expression like {{book.title}},{{book.author}},{{book.publisher}} so that I can see the book details? Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its typo in controller name inside `bookEdit` state.

it should

```
controller: 'bookEditCtrl'
```

instead of

```
controller: 'bookEditlCtrl'
```

**Corrected State**

```
.state('bookEdit', {
    url: '/edit/books/:bookId',
    templateUrl: 'bookEdit.ng.html',
    controller: 'bookEditCtrl' //<--change here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works! i reviewed my code 10 times but I was not able to detect the typo. Thanks again

Comment: @SandroPalmieri no probs..could you accept the answer?